# How to do Winrar in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, winrar, sfx

In the actual UI of WinRAR you can create an sfx file and have the following sfx options:

**Under General Tab:**
Path to extract: Create in current folder

**Under Modes Tab:**
Silent mode: Hide all

**Under Text And Icon Tab:**
Load the SFX Icon from the file: *Choose the certain file*

How would I do this using batch files?

Also, how would I add a directory, rather than just a single file using the batch method?

I'm not too good with batch files, heck - I ain't ever done batch files - I was just looking at the switches and I couldn't figure out how I would do it. Please, if someone could tell me or even guide me, it will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use the winrar command line, A GUI is not conducive to manipulation via a batch file.

E.g;

```
winrar a -sfx -z"XXX.INI" OUTPUT.EXE
```

`XXX.INI` is a text file that contains the sfx options as shown under "*SFX Commands*" in the WinRar help file, e.g. `silent=1`.

(There is also a *SFX commands: script sample*)

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept as soon as I have successfully done what I need to do, if that's ok =]

Comment: Cheers, got what I wanted done, now just gotta find out all the commands that I can use in the config file. Thanks, again.

Comment: At this page you can find those commands: http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/ or, more specifically, http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/html/helpguisfxscript.htm